# Problem with Vars when trying to update from v4 to v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

**Hi!**
I'm trying to update this script from v4 to v5, but im having a few issues. I already changed a few functions but the real problem is with the Vars. Could anyone give me a tip on how to solve this?

**Thank you.**

```
sym = input(title="Symbol", type=input.symbol, defval="BTC1!")
cme_btc = request.security(sym, "1D", close)

f_c_gradientAdvDecPro(_source, _center, _steps, _c_bearWeak, _c_bearStrong, _c_bullWeak, _c_bullStrong) =>
    var float _qtyAdvDec = 0.
    var float _maxSteps  = ta.max(1, _steps)
    bool  _xUp     = ta.crossover(_source, _center)
    bool  _xDn     = ta.crossunder(_source, _center)
    float _chg     = ta.change(_source)
    bool  _up      = _chg > 0
    bool  _dn      = _chg < 0
    bool  _srcBull = _source > _center
    bool  _srcBear = _source < _center
    _qtyAdvDec := 
      _srcBull ? _xUp ? 1 : _up ? ta.min(_maxSteps, _qtyAdvDec + 1) : _dn ? ta.max(1, _qtyAdvDec - 1) : _qtyAdvDec :
      _srcBear ? _xDn ? 1 : _dn ? ta.min(_maxSteps, _qtyAdvDec + 1) : _up ? ta.max(1, _qtyAdvDec - 1) : _qtyAdvDec : _qtyAdvDec
    var color _return = na
    _return := 
      _srcBull ? color.from_gradient(_qtyAdvDec, 1, _maxSteps, _c_bullWeak, _c_bullStrong) : 
      _srcBear ? color.from_gradient(_qtyAdvDec, 1, _maxSteps, _c_bearWeak, _c_bearStrong) : _return

var color _C_PRIMARY = #399e46
var color _C_SECONDARY = #fc2d0d

var C_PRIMARY = input(_C_PRIMARY, title="Bull")
var C_SECONDARY = input(_C_SECONDARY, title="Bear")

friday_close = valuewhen(dayofweek.friday == dayofweek, cme_btc, 0)
plot(hour)
should_plot = (dayofweek.friday == dayofweek and hour > 23) or dayofweek.saturday == dayofweek or dayofweek.sunday == dayofweek

p1 = plot(should_plot ? close : na, title='Candle Close', color=color.new(C_PRIMARY, 100), style=plot.style_linebr)
p2 = plot(should_plot ? friday_close : na, title="CME Close", color=color.new(C_SECONDARY, 100), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3)
color cc = f_c_gradientAdvDecPro(close, friday_close, 15, color.new(C_PRIMARY, 70), C_PRIMARY, color.new(C_SECONDARY, 70), C_SECONDARY)
fill(p1, p2, cc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the original code (v4), is this

https://www.tradingview.com/script/XIS9utVx-CME-Gap-BTC/

You can convert it automatically

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#v4-to-v5-converter

And you get this code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © anche1991

//@version=5
indicator('anche/cme_gap_btc', overlay=true)
sym = input.symbol(title='Symbol', defval='BTC1!')
cme_btc = request.security(sym, '1D', close)

// Gradient function copied from PineCoders https://www.tradingview.com/v/hqH4YIFa/
f_c_gradientAdvDecPro(_source, _center, _steps, _c_bearWeak, _c_bearStrong, _c_bullWeak, _c_bullStrong) =>
    var float _qtyAdvDec = 0.
    var float _maxSteps = math.max(1, _steps)
    bool _xUp = ta.crossover(_source, _center)
    bool _xDn = ta.crossunder(_source, _center)
    float _chg = ta.change(_source)
    bool _up = _chg > 0
    bool _dn = _chg < 0
    bool _srcBull = _source > _center
    bool _srcBear = _source < _center
    _qtyAdvDec := _srcBull ? _xUp ? 1 : _up ? math.min(_maxSteps, _qtyAdvDec + 1) : _dn ? math.max(1, _qtyAdvDec - 1) : _qtyAdvDec : _srcBear ? _xDn ? 1 : _dn ? math.min(_maxSteps, _qtyAdvDec + 1) : _up ? math.max(1, _qtyAdvDec - 1) : _qtyAdvDec : _qtyAdvDec
    var color _return = na
    _return := _srcBull ? color.from_gradient(_qtyAdvDec, 1, _maxSteps, _c_bullWeak, _c_bullStrong) : _srcBear ? color.from_gradient(_qtyAdvDec, 1, _maxSteps, _c_bearWeak, _c_bearStrong) : _return
    _return

var color _C_PRIMARY = #399e46
var color _C_SECONDARY = #fc2d0d

var C_PRIMARY = input(_C_PRIMARY, title='Bull')
var C_SECONDARY = input(_C_SECONDARY, title='Bear')

friday_close = ta.valuewhen(dayofweek.friday == dayofweek, cme_btc, 0)
plot(hour)
should_plot = dayofweek.friday == dayofweek and hour > 23 or dayofweek.saturday == dayofweek or dayofweek.sunday == dayofweek

p1 = plot(should_plot ? close : na, title='Candle Close', color=color.new(C_PRIMARY, 100), style=plot.style_linebr)
p2 = plot(should_plot ? friday_close : na, title='CME Close', color=color.new(C_SECONDARY, 100), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=3)
color cc = f_c_gradientAdvDecPro(close, friday_close, 15, color.new(C_PRIMARY, 70), C_PRIMARY, color.new(C_SECONDARY, 70), C_SECONDARY)
fill(p1, p2, cc)
```